# change format from %Y%m%d%H%M% to another format

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

how can I change date format from `"%Y%m%d%H%M"` to `"%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M"` in shell scripting?

there is a log file (logfile.txt) with date format as `"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"` in first column. what is needed is print first column like `"%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M"`.

e.g: from 201804041323 to 2018-04-04 13:23

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? Being that StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects us to [try to solve our own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Can you fix the upstream process that creates the unwanted date format?

Comment: it is not something unwanted. I am trying to store date with second format in new file.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/$1-$2-$3 $4:$5/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

sed -r 's/^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5/g' logfile.txt > newlogfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command for getting output in format of "2018-04-18 22:14"

date +%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M